# Oracle VM Virtual box on windows 7 boot error: lvmetad is not active yet

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Oracle VM VirtualBox installed on my windows 7 machine; when I try to start my instance on VM, I get the following error and the VM doesn't boot up:

```
 lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root contains a file system with errors, checks forced
 Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found

 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e. , without -a or -p options)
 fsck exited with status code 4
 The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck

 BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
 Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commnads.

 (initramfs)_
```

I'm not familiar at all with VM or ubuntu - can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Off-topic for this site; but [this might help](https://askubuntu.com/q/697190)?

Comment: @AlexPoole - that is similar but not exactly my issue but I used it as a guide. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using Alex Poole's link as a guide. I did

```
fsck /dev/<my partition name>
```

and clicked yes to all. Powered off the machine and rebooted again and it booted back up.